# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have entity `Acteur` related to entity `Categorieacteur` but when I do persist and flush I have this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Acteur::setIdcategacteur()
>   must be an instance of Categorieacteur, string given, called in
>   D:\wamp\www\GestionDesEvenements\Ajout_Acteur.php on line 16 and
>   defined in D:\wamp\www\GestionDesEvenements\entity\Acteur.php on line
>   342

This is the relation in entity Acteur:

```
    /**
 * @var \Categorieacteur
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorieacteur")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="idCategActeur", referencedColumnName="idCategActeur")
 * })
 */
private $idcategacteur;

    /**
 * Set idcategacteur
 *
 * @param \Categorieacteur $idcategacteur
 * @return Acteur
 */
public function setIdcategacteur(\Categorieacteur $idcategacteur = null)
{
    $this->idcategacteur = $idcategacteur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idcategacteur
 *
 * @return \Categorieacteur
 */
public function getIdcategacteur()
{
    return $this->idcategacteur;
}
```

and this is the code of persist :

```
<?php
require_once 'em.php';

$Ac = new Acteur();

$Ac->setMail($_POST['email']);
$Ac->setAdracteur($_POST['AdrAct']);
$Ac->setMotDePasse($_POST['MotDePasse']);
$Ac->setSiteWeb($_POST['SiteWeb']); 
$Ac->setLogin($_POST['login']);
$Ac->setEtatacteur($_POST['etat']);

$Ca=new Categorieacteur();
$Ac->setIdcategacteur($_POST['categ']);


$em->persist($Ac);
$em->flush();
```

and this is the form (the form works fine):

```
        Catégorie:
        <select name="categ" size="1" id="categ" onChange="AfficherElement();">
        <?php
            require_once 'em.php';

            //print_r($_POST);
            $lc=$em->getRepository('Categorieacteur')->findAll();
            foreach($lc as $c)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$c->getidcatact()."'>".$c->getdesigncat()."</option>";
            }
        ?>


        </select>


?>
```

Comment: The method is expecting an instance of \Categorieacteur class but you are passing a string $Ac->setIdcategacteur($_POST['categ'])

Comment: @noia_0328 : I did not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$Ac->setIdcategacteur($em->getRepository('MyBundle:Categorieacteur')->find($_POST['categ']));
```

instead of

```
$Ac->setIdcategacteur($_POST['categ']);
```